# Fire the plugin swipebox on load with links that include hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, popup

html code:

```
<a id="image1" href="images/1.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption">
    <img src="images/1mini.jpg" alt="image" />
</a>
```

Js code for firing the pugin when user enters with link that ends with '#1'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.location.hash == "#1") {
            $( '#image1' ).swipebox();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I figured it out that the js code

```
$( '#image1' ).swipebox();
```

works only when I click on the image. But I need that during the page load it would be popuped already.

Comment: Explain what is not working after debugging your code.

Comment: I do not know how to debug. I understand that '.swipebox();' calls the plugin, so I did. When I alert msg with link #1, it shows, which means that the problem is with  '$( '#1' ).swipebox();'

Comment: `id="1"` is invalid. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: I changed this id but it did not work

Comment: put the alert inside `if(window.location.hash == "#1") {` and cross verify that code execution reaches inside that if condition.

Comment: Yes, alert is working inside `if(window.location.hash == "#1") {`

Comment: could you please update your question with updated HTML and JS code?

Comment: I have just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the `swipebox` on page load; could you please try with following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.location.hash == "#1") {
            $( '#image1' ).swipebox();
            $( '#image1' ).click();//click the image programmatically
        }
    });
</script>
```